# <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="NewProduct.Name"/>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My input form is not working at all even the mouse is not affected 
Here is the code:

```
<div id="product-page" ng-controller="ProductCtrl" ng-init="init()">

<form class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">NAME:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="NewProduct.Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">SURNAME :</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.Surname"/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">PRODUCT:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.Name" ng-options="product.id as product.name for product in Products"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Save()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I didn't see mistakes in here 
maybe then in the js code:

```
CoffeeApp.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.Products;

    $scope.GetProducts = function () {
        $.post('/Product/GetProducts', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.Products = data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Define "Not working".

Comment: Your GetProducts function actually $.post in it (maybe it should be get?)

Comment: The `ngInit`  directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses. You should use Components or Controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Instead of using jQuery `.post`, the code should use the [AngularJS $http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).